# How to configure atom to use python 3.x ide?

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

I am using Linux (solus Linux). I installed atom and need to know what package to install to use python 3.x.I have tried one of the package but it works with python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried doing a search? `sudo eopkg search python` and see if there is a package named something like `python3`. You may also need a development package, they are often named something like `python3-devel`.

Comment: yep @DanLowe python 3 is installed its python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a code

```
!# /usr/bin/python3
```

at the top of my script helped me.
Also install scripts and configure it to use python3 instead